# Reasons for "ajaxform is not a function" error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, ajaxform

I'm using JQuery form / ajax.form to upload images to my server and database - I've been having no luck using it effectively in Firefox 19.0.2, however it's working completely fine in Opera, Chrome and Safari. Any ideas why I might be getting the error on Firefox?  Please help

Here is the code that's the showing the problem (target: '#preview'):

```
                <script type="text/javascript" >
                $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('#photoimg').live('change', function()
                { 
                $("#preview").html('');
                $("#current").hide();
                $("#preview").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading file...."/>');
                $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                target: '#preview'
                }).submit();
                });
                }); 
                </script>
                <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='update-user-profile.php'>

                Upload image from your computer: <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" /><br><br/>

                </form>
                <div id='preview'></div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's not possible to say. The error means exactly what it says; the value of a symbol called "ajaxform" is being used as if it were a function, and it isn't.

Comment: Well why is it that it's working in all other browsers except Firefox? I wouldn't have thought that was a coding error?

Comment: What have you done to investigate the problem?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint with Firebug, or something like that?

Comment: I've run it through error consoles in browsers and it came back with ajaxform is not a function - I've updated my question

Comment: Please provide more code/other plugins used

Comment: Well, if it's not a function, what is it? Are you sure you're correctly including the jQuery plugin that adds the "ajaxForm" method?

Comment: (Also `.live()` is long-deprecated.  Instead you can use `$('body').on('change', '#photoimg', function() { ...` )

Comment: Yes I am using <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> and JQuery 1.7 so live should still work, however I've also tried it with .on and no luck there either

Comment: Did you include the scripts in this order: jQuery, Form.js and then this script?

Comment: Yes, Jquery, then Form in the head + the script in the body above the form

Comment: Hmmm, seems like other people are having problems too: https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/304

Comment: Thankyou for that @Florija, It's been driving me nuts for the past 5 hours trying to work out what's wrong with MY code and it's Firefox - Will have to continue to use it and hope there's a fix for it in the next Firefox update

Comment: I think we should close this question now

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been filed as bug on [github](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/304) and cannot be solved immediately at this moment (Browser bug?).